# Service writing to a database and activity reads from it

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, loader

Architecture help needed. I'm building an app which will consist from `Service` and `Activity`. `Service` will write data to `SQLite` DB and `Activity` should read it and display. There are two problems: 1) `Activity` should receive updates on-the-fly. 2) If `Activity` goes background it should load all the changes when it returns foreground.

After two days of research I assume that the only way to implement it is creating `ContentProvider` as the middle layer and using `CursorLoader` in Activity. Am I right? Any other suggestions? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is making your own observer pattern implementation. Here is my version:

**The observer**

```
/**
 * Receives notification of updates on database contents.
 */
public interface DatabaseObserver {
    /**
     * This method is called if the observable database's notifyObservers 
     * method is called (because the observable database has been updated.
     */
    void onUpdate(String tableName);
}
```

**The observable**

```
/**
 * Used to notify a group of Observer objects when a change occurs.
 */
public interface ObservableDatabase {
    /**
     * Adds the specified observer to the list of observers.
     */
    void addObserver(DatabaseObserver observer);

    /**
     * Removes the specified observer from the list of observers.
     */
    void removeObserver(DatabaseObserver observer);
}
```

**The database helper**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements ObservableDatabase {
    private static DatabaseHelper sInstance;

    private CopyOnWriteArrayList<DatabaseObserver> mObservers = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Returns the single instance of Database helper
     */
    public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        }

        return sInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_STATEMENT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(DROP_STATEMENT);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Adds the specified observer to the list of observers.
     */
    public void addObserver(DatabaseObserver observer) {
        mObservers.addIfAbsent(observer);
    }

    /**
     * Removes the specified observer from the list of observers.
     */
    public void removeObserver(DatabaseObserver observer) {
        mObservers.remove(observer);
    }

    private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE);
    }

    private void notifyObservers(String tableName) {
        for (DatabaseObserver observer: mObservers) {
            observer.onUpdate(tableName);
        }
    }
}
```

Note, that each writing method in your database helper should call notifyObservers(tableName) after modifying the database.

Now, any component can subscribe to this database helper to be updated. And make sure that the activity is not dead in the onUpdate callback before you try to update the UI.

Comment: what method should I call when onUpdate() gets triggered? should I throw previous Loader and re-init a new one?

Comment: If you are using a Loader, I suggest to make the loader an observer in onStartLoading() and in the onUpdate callback after checking that the modified table is of interest you just invoke onContentChanged()

Comment: I also suggest extending AsyncTaskLoader.